# Replace tags in text file using key-value pairs from JSON file

Tags: json, bash, shell, dictionary, jq

I am trying to write a shell script that can read a json string, decode it to an array and foreach through the array and use the key/value for replacing strings in another file.

If this were PHP, then I would write something like this.

```
$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  str_replace($key, $value, $rawString);
}
```

I need this to be converted to Bash script.
Here is the example JSON string.

```
{
  "login": "lambda",
  "id": 37398,
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/37398?v=3",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/lambda",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/lambda",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lambda/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lambda/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lambda/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lambda/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lambda/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lambda/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lambda/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lambda/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/lambda/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false,
  "name": "Brian Campbell",
  "company": null,
  "blog": null,
  "location": null,
  "email": null,
  "hireable": null,
  "bio": null,
  "public_repos": 27,
  "public_gists": 23,
  "followers": 8,
  "following": 2,
  "created_at": "2008-11-30T21:03:27Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-12-21T23:53:11Z"
}
```

I've this file,

> ```
> Lamba login name is %login%, and avatar url is %avatar_url%
> ```

I am using jq

```
jq -c '.[]' /tmp/json | while read i; do
   echo $i
done
```

This outputs only the value part. How do I loop through key and also get value?

Also, I've found that the keys of the json string can be returned using

```
jq  'keys' /tmp/params
```

However, I am still trying to figure out how to loop through the key and return the data.

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing can be done quite simply (and very efficiently) in jq.

For the sake of illustration, suppose we have defined `dictionary` to be the dictionary object given in the question, and `template` to be the template string:

```
def dictionary: { ...... };

def template: 
  "Lamba login name is %login%, and avatar url is %avatar_url%";
```

Then the required interpolation can be performed as follows:

```
dictionary
| reduce to_entries[] as $pair (template; gsub("%\($pair.key)%"; $pair.value))
```

The above produces:

```
"Lamba login name is lambda, and avatar url is https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/37398?v=3"
```

There are of course many other ways in which the dictionary and template string can be presented.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  Not everyone has access to a jq with regex support, so it's nice to have some kind of alternative, even if (as you carefully noted) it has its caveats.   You might like to document what I believe is a fairly robust workaround -- using a control character (e.g. control-A) as the sed delimiter.  It's robust at least to the extent that JSON does not allow raw control characters in JSON strings.

Comment: I thought of adding that explicitly, but it's been asked and answered before - I might try and find that Q&A and link to it. Question about your solution: is it possible to have both the contents of `dictionary` and `template` in external files? Obviously, you can use `jq -n 'def template: "..."; reduce ...' < dict.json`, but using two external files?

Comment: Oh, figured it out: something like `jq --arg template "$(< template)"` and then use as `$template` within the jq command.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - Yes, that is one option. With jq 1.5, if reading from a file, the simplest is probably to use the --argfile option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your JSON is in `infile.json` and the text with the tags to be replaced in `infile.txt`.

Here is an entirely unreadable one-liner that does it:

```
$ sed -f <(jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @tsv' < infile.json | sed 's~^~s|%~;s~\t~%|~;s~$~|g~') infile.txt
Lamba login name is lambda, and avatar url is https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/37398?v=3
```

Now, to decipher what this does. First, a few linebreaks for readability:

```
sed -f <(
    jq -r '
        to_entries[] |
        [.key, .value] |
        @tsv
    ' < infile.json |
    sed '
        s~^~s|%~
        s~\t~%|~
        s~$~|g~
    '
) infile.txt
```

We're basically using a sed command that takes its instructions from a file; instead of an actual file, we use process substitution to generate the sed commands:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @tsv' < infile.json |
    sed 's~^~s|%~;s~\t~%|~;s~$~|g~'
```

Some processing with jq, followed by some sed substitutions.

This is what the jq command does:

- Generate raw output (no quotes, actual tabs instead of `\t`) with the [`-r`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Invokingjq) option
- Turn the input JSON object into an array of key-value pairs with the [`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) function, resulting in

  ```
  [
    {
      "key": "login",
      "value": "lambda"
    },
    {
      "key": "id",
      "value": 37398
    },
    ...
  ```

  ]
- Get all elements of the array with [`[]`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#.[]):

  ```
  {
    "key": "login",
    "value": "lambda"
  }
  {
    "key": "id",
    "value": 37398
  }
  ...
  ```
- Get a list of arrays with key/value in each using [`[.key, .value]`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Arrayconstruction-[]), resulting in

  ```
  [
    "login",
    "lambda"
  ]
  [
    "id",
    37398
  ]
  ...
  ```
- Finally, use the [`@tsv`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Formatstringsandescaping) filter to get the key-value pairs as a tab separated list:

  ```
  login   lambda
  id      37398
  ...
  ```

Now, we pipe this to sed, which performs three substitutions:

- `s~^~s|%~` – add `s|%` to the beginning of each line
- `s~\t~%|~` – replace the tab with `%|`
- `s~$~|g~` – add `|g` to the end of each line

This gives us a sed file that looks as follows:

```
s|%login%|lambda|g
s|%id%|37398|g
s|%avatar_url%|https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/37398?v=3|g
```

Notice that for these substitutions, we used `~` as the delimiter, and for the substitution commands we generated, we used `|` – mostly to avoid running into problems with strings containing `/`.

If this sed file were stored as `commands.sed`, the overall command would correspond to

```
sed -f commands.sed infile.txt
```

---

**Remarks**

- If  your shell doesn't support process substitution, you could make sed read from standard input instead, using `sed -f -`:

  ```
  jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @tsv' < infile.json |
      sed 's~^~s|%~;s~\t~%|~;s~$~|g~' |
      sed -f - infile.txt
  ```
- If `infile.json` contained `|` or `~`, you would have to choose different delimiters for the sed substitutions (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844945/3266847) about using a non-printable character as a delimiter) or even perform additional substitutions to get rid of the delimiting characters first and put them back in at the end (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/3266847) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/3266847) Q&A).
- Some seds (such as BSD sed found in MacOS) have trouble with `\t` used in the pattern to substitute. If that is the case, the command `s~\t~%|~` has to be replaced by `s~'$'\t''~%|~` to "splice in" the tab character, or (if the shell doesn't support ANSI-C quoting) even with `s~'"$(printf '\t')"'~%|~`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple sed solution. Assume that the json Object is in x.json and the file where the replacements should be done in f.txt.
The following x.sed - Programm called as

```
sed -n -f x.sed x.json <(echo FILE_DELIM) f.txt
```

does the job.

x.sed:

```
1,$H
$ {
    x
    :b
    s/\("\([^"]\+\)" *: *\(\("\([^"]*\)"\)\|\(\(\w\|\.\)\+\)\).*FILE_DELIM.*\)%\2%\(.*\)/\1\3\8/
    tb
    s/.*FILE_DELIM\n//
    p
}
```

The trick is to save the two files (separated by the string FILE_DELIM) in one line in sed's hold space and then recursively replace the keys (e.g. %login%) by their values behind the FILE_DELIM.
The crucial point is to define the pattern which matches a key value pair in the json object. Here I used:

" followed by non " followed by " followed by blanks followed by a colon (*1) followed by blanks followed by (again a qouted string or a string consisting of (word characters or .)) (*2)

The backreference \2 in the search pattern matches the key and is replaced with \3 which matches the value.

*1): Up to here this matches a key like "login"

*2): The values are allowed to be "xyz", "", abc, 0.1, ...